# Migrating MySQL database contents to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I refactored a project and wanted to try out PostgreSQL instead of MySQL. I now want to migrate the table contents of some tables.

The problem is, when I use a select query like this (don't bother about the names, is just an example)

`SELECT id AS id_x, name AS name_x, name2 AS name2_x`

I want to export the table data and import it into MySQL. The problem is, that the syntax for `INSERT INTO` is different in MySQL and PostgreSQL. I don't want to export the whole table, because I also changed some parts of the structure, tried to make it more performant etc. So I just want to get the table data, but I need those `AS x` thing, because the names of the columns have changed

I already found several links on this topic.

I can use `mysqldump` to dump the table and set the `--compatible=name` parameter. The problem here is, that I can't add a `SELECT` statement, right? I can only add a `where` check.

Then, I could use the `mysql` command to export the query I want, but mysql doesn't have any `compatible` parameter. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider to create a temporaty table by issuing

```
SELECT id AS id_x, name AS name_x, name2 AS name2_x FROM oldtable INTO temptable
```

And then as a second step export the temptable using mysqldump with the `--compatible=` parameter.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: I'm an idiot for not thinking about that haha. Thank you!